# Mapping Large Dataset to Categories with scoring

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, artificial-intelligence

Trying to figure out the best way to approach this problem.

I have a list of a few hundred thousand food items.  The pieces of data I have are: Description (basically Item Name), Food Category, Ingredients (Food Item table)

I am trying to match each food item with a food category that exists in a different data set.  These food categories are partitioned a little differently so there is not a 1 to 1 mapping to the food category in the food items table.  The fields are have for this data-set are: Main Category, Sub Category & Product Examples. (Food Category Table)

In the Food Item table the Food Category may be wrong or generalized.  Basically the Food Categories in the Food Item table are general where the Food Categories in the Food Category table are more specific.

I am looking to create an algorithm that looks at a specific food item (in the food items tables) and matches it with a "recommended" entry in the Food Category Table.  Possibly giving me the top 5 choices and a score (or percentage match) for each.

If possible I would like this to learn over time based on manual corrections/interventions, past mappings, etc...  Not sure if AI is correct terminology to use here.

This data is stored in SQL Server 2016.  The application around it is in ASP.Net (C#)

Again looking for the best way to approach this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you have some sample data already categorized correctly to be used as guide for the algorithm.

Let's assume you have some food already categorized:

```
Name          Category  Ingredients
Apple         Fruit     Apple
Cheesecake    Dessert   Apple, Butter, Flour, Sugar, Cheese
Cheeseburger  Junk      Bread, Tomato, Cheese, Meat
```

The algorithm should count in which category each ingredient is categorized, giving a relative percentage. Something like

```
Ingredient    Category  Percentage
Apple         Fruit     56
Apple         Dessert   34
Apple         Salad      6
Apple         Drink      4
Cheese        Sandwich  70
Cheese        Junk      21
Cheese        Dessert    7
Cheese        Salad      2
```

Then, when you have an unclassified food, you just sum the percentage of all ingredients and order them by Category.

You should consider adding some weight so that the total score for all the ingredients of a food is always 1. For example, if you have a food with 4 ingredients, each will score only 0.25. This will reduce the importance of an ingredient in very complicated recipes.